# Use PHP to access LinkedIn API without user login

Tags: php, oauth, linkedin-api

I'm trying to automate a data pull from MY company page on linked in via the API. This will be a server side job with no user intervention.

I have credentials to log into linkedin and a REST API Application with keys as per:
https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/quick-start-guide

I want to be able to pull the contents of my wall nightly to aggregate it to my social media site.

Is there a way to obtain and store the Oauth token server side and not require or fake the client session piece?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, but a token can expire so you need renew it when needed.

Here is an example: https://github.com/EJTH/SLinkedIn/blob/master/examples/reusing-tokens.php

If you run a cron then dont authorize, but handle exceptions to reset the token and force the user to renew it on the next login.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is because LinkedIn doesn't allow it.

I've run into the same problem and it seems there may be a way to keep it open longer, but it looks like LinkedIn explicitly bans automated actions in their terms of service. Simply put, I don't believe any automated action can be initiated except by a member.

[This gets into more detail on their stance on automated requests:](http://developer.linkedin.com/forum/use-oauthcallback-get-verifier)