# How to fetch Linkedin feeds from my company page without user having to authenticate

Tags: php, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I am trying to display my linkedin company page updates on my site as indicated here.

https://developer.linkedin.com/reading-company-shares

I downloaded the source from here
http://thinkdiff.net/linkedin/integrate-linkedin-api-in-your-site/

and the added the following method in linkedin.php

```
function company($parameters)
    {
    //$search_url = $this->base_url."/v1/companies/{$parameters}/updates";
    //$search_url = $this->base_url . "/v1/people-search?keywords=facebook";
    $search_url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/918677/updates?";



    echo "Performing search for: " . $parameters . "<br />";
    echo "Search URL: $search_url <br />";

    $request = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($this->consumer, $this->access_token, "GET", $search_url);
    $request->sign_request($this->signature_method, $this->consumer, $this->access_token);
    $auth_header = $request->to_header("https://api.linkedin.com");
    print_r($auth_header);
    $response = $this->httpRequest($search_url, $auth_header, "GET");
    return $response;
}
```

I am unable to make it work. Also I am trying to show them without the user having to login.
Is it possible ? Any same code or tutorial will be helpful.

Thanks..

Comment: What have you tried? What worked, what didn't? Where is the problem so far?

Comment: I am kind of stuck at the very begining.
The Primary question is it possible to fetch my company feeds without asking the users to login when they visit my site ? If yes, what steps should I follow.

Comment: Did you resolve this? If so I would really like to know the answer!

Comment: No I was not able to resolve it without loggin any user in

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15104153/use-php-to-access-linkedin-api-without-user-login

Answer (score 0):

First you have to get user token of `linkedin` user Use `Socialite` or REST API package for `oauth`.

Once you having user token it is pretty simple to fetch Company list under admin user

```
$token = 'uflefjefheilhfbwrfliehbwfeklfw';    // user token
$api_url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies?oauth2_access_token=".$token."&format=json&is-company-admin=true";
$pages = json_decode(file_get_contents($api_url));
```

You have get `$pages` json array of list of company profile.